# How to create File object Javascript/angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, file-upload

Requirement 1. In my project, a page requires user to upload a document which is done by using an angular directive (3rd party). When user hits submit button, the posted file is accessed in ASP.NET MVC controller (Request.Files). This file is finally saved on the Web Server.

Requirement 2. A user can also edit the form wherein all uploaded documents are to be shown. Here user can add/remove documents as well as can view the uploaded documents.

Requirement 1 is achieved successfully by using an angular directive.

When a file is browsed and selected, the angular directive creates JavaScript File object. So I believe to achieve Requirement 2, I should also create JavaScript File object array programmatically to fulfill the requirement of the angular directive.

So when the page opens in edit mode, I create a JSON object in ASP.NET MVC controller and passes it to the angular controller where I try to create JavaScript File object array and then passes it to the angular directive.

The File object array is created as below:

```
$scope.files = [];
var uploadedFiles = [{fileContent:a byte array, fileName:'doc1.txt'}]; //this comes from the Web Server
$scope.files.push(new File(uploadedFiles[0].fileContent , "filename.txt", {type: "text/plain", lastModified: date}));
```

The above code does not throw any error but when I click the file name it downloads the byte array as string not the original file content.

Please suggest how to achieve the same.

Comment: I also tried to fill the files array by the JSON object (but not as JavaScript File object) and when user clicks on the link, it calls a controller action which writes the stream on response object. It works. But when I try to upload another document, the upload directive only considers the newly uploaded document and discards the previously uploaded document because it is not a JavaScript File object.